# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faker'

Tags: python, faker

I am trying to install `faker` package and I got a message that is successfully installed
But when trying the code `from faker import Faker`, I got a message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faker'`

I have tried to uninstall it `pip uninstall Faker` then I used this line to install it again `python -m pip install Faker` but the problem is still there.
Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Are you also running your code with `python yourScript.py?`

Comment: Do you have matching versions of pip and python? Can you show the value of pip --version in the terminal

Comment: I was running python script with `py test.py` and when I used `python test.py`, the problem was solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: pip version `pip 22.0.4 from c:\users\future\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: Have you ensured you are in the correct environment and have you run `pip freeze` to check if the package is installed in your current environment? (I can't post comments yet, so sorry for putting this as answer)

Comment: In my env I just had python3 installed, so `faker` definitely does not work with pip3, so I had to install python2 and install faker with pip.
This does not work: `pip3 install faker` - it says "Import 'faker' could not be resolved - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faker'"
This works: `pip install faker`

Answer (score 4):

Install faker in Anaconda prompt using the following code:

```
pip install faker
```

Answer (score 4):

(virtual environment:vagrant)
I encountered the same problem but fixed it by `pip uninstall faker` from the current directory and then adding "faker=={version}" in `requirements.txt`, then `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: This solution worked for me after trying to uninstall and install `faker` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run python script with:

`python3 YourScriptName.py`

Not `python YourScriptName.py`